# how can i change dtype on my pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, regex

```
50s
20s
30s
40s
```

this is my Data Frame before that use regular expression

i use regular expression to remove s and it's below

```
import re

def split_it(data):
    return re.findall('(\d+)',data)

df_plot['age'] = df_plot['age'].apply(lambda x:split_it(x))
```

but that's result is not good. like below

```
[50]
[30]
[50]
[20]
```

**so how do i convert data type on my dataframe only digit????**

Answer (score 1):

You could do

#### Solution 1:

change the fucntion and leave the second line unchanged

```
def split_it(data):
    return re.findall('(\d+)',data)[0]

df_plot['age'] = df_plot['age'].apply(lambda x:split_it(x))
```

#### Solution 2

leave the function unchanged and change the second line

```
def split_it(data):
    return re.findall('(\d+)',data)

df_plot['age'] = df_plot['age'].apply(lambda x:split_it(x)).str[0]
```

Comment: I think it's a bit overcomplicated. If the data is always with a final "s" and that's it, you don't need regex and you can just use `df_plot['age'][:-1]`

Comment: First of all your code would not work. To make it work as you intend you need to change it like this `df_plot['age'].str[:-1]`. Second without any other specifics from the OP I thought it would have been better to leave the code unchanged as much as possible. But if that is the only use case I agree with you using regular expression is not needed

Comment: that you for your teaching. it was really helpfull!